# Partial application / Ambiguous call when two generics have the same type

Tags: c#

```cs
public static Action<T2> Partial<T1, T2>(this Action<T1, T2> action, T1 arg1) => arg2 => action(arg1, arg2);

public static Action<T1> Partial<T1, T2>(this Action<T1, T2> action, T2 arg2) => arg1 => action(arg1, arg2);
```

If `typeof(T1) == typeof(T2)`, is there any way to help the compiler distinguish between the two?

Comment: Why do you have both versions? This seems like a fundamental limitation.

Comment: Why would you have *either* method?  Calling this method is more work and less clear than just inlining its contents.

Comment: Similar, maybe dupe https://stackoverflow.com/q/5655411/1043380

Comment: @Servy From a functional programming POV, I personally find this reasonably clear and inlining its contents is more work.

Comment: @Sweeper From a functional programming POV, I personally find this objectively ambiguous (so much so that the code doesn't even compile because the compiler cannot resolve the ambiguity).  It results in more code. Adding a lambda adds 3 characters, this adds a ton more.  It's more typing, it's more work for the compiler, it's more work for the runtime, and it's so ambiguous as to which parameter is/isn't being applied it often doesn't even compile.  As opposed to seeing a lambda that most programmers would use multiple times daily and not even need to need to think about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple way to differentiate between them is with argument names:

```
var a = (int x, int y) => Console.WriteLine($"{x} {y}");
a.Partial(arg2: 1); // calls second overload
a.Partial(arg1: 1); // calls first overload
```

That said, I would say using different names would be clearer, e.g. calling them `Partial1`, `Partial2` etc. You need to think about which parameter you want to partially apply when you do this anyway - it shouldn't hurt to write that number down.

---

As a cursed solution (:D), you can add a optional parameter to one of the overloads to make the compiler prefer the other overload:

```
public static Action<T1> Partial<T1, T2>(
    this Action<T1, T2> action, 
    T2 arg2,
    Unused unused = null
) => arg1 => action(arg1, arg2);
```

`Unused` can be a un-instantiable class.

```
public sealed class Unused {
    private Unused() {}
}
```